# Transform a Pandas dataframe in a pandas with multicolumns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following pandas dataframe, where the column `id` is the dataframe index

```
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
|    |   price_A |   amount_A |   price_B |   amount_b |
|----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------|
|  0 | 0.652826  |  0.941421  |  0.823048 |  0.728427  |
|  1 | 0.400078  |  0.600585  |  0.194912 |  0.269842  |
|  2 | 0.223524  |  0.146675  |  0.375459 |  0.177165  |
|  3 | 0.330626  |  0.214981  |  0.389855 |  0.541666  |
|  4 | 0.578132  |  0.30478   |  0.789573 |  0.268851  |
|  5 | 0.0943601 |  0.514878  |  0.419333 |  0.0170096 |
|  6 | 0.279122  |  0.401132  |  0.722363 |  0.337094  |
|  7 | 0.444977  |  0.333254  |  0.643878 |  0.371528  |
|  8 | 0.724673  |  0.0632807 |  0.345225 |  0.935403  |
|  9 | 0.905482  |  0.8465    |  0.585653 |  0.364495  |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

And I want to convert this dataframe in to a multi column data frame, that looks like this

```
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
|    |           A            |           B            |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
| id |   price   |   amount   |   price   |   amount   |
|----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------|
|  0 | 0.652826  |  0.941421  |  0.823048 |  0.728427  |
|  1 | 0.400078  |  0.600585  |  0.194912 |  0.269842  |
|  2 | 0.223524  |  0.146675  |  0.375459 |  0.177165  |
|  3 | 0.330626  |  0.214981  |  0.389855 |  0.541666  |
|  4 | 0.578132  |  0.30478   |  0.789573 |  0.268851  |
|  5 | 0.0943601 |  0.514878  |  0.419333 |  0.0170096 |
|  6 | 0.279122  |  0.401132  |  0.722363 |  0.337094  |
|  7 | 0.444977  |  0.333254  |  0.643878 |  0.371528  |
|  8 | 0.724673  |  0.0632807 |  0.345225 |  0.935403  |
|  9 | 0.905482  |  0.8465    |  0.585653 |  0.364495  |
+----+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

I've tried transforming my old pandas dataframe in to a dict this way:

```
   dict = {"A": df[["price_a","amount_a"]], "B":df[["price_b", "amount_b"]]}
   df = pd.DataFrame(dict, index=df.index)
```

But I had no success, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming columns manually:

```
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([x.split('_')[::-1] for x in df.columns])
df.index.name='id'
```

Output:

```
           A                   B         b
       price    amount     price    amount
id                                        
0   0.652826  0.941421  0.823048  0.728427
1   0.400078  0.600585  0.194912  0.269842
2   0.223524  0.146675  0.375459  0.177165
3   0.330626  0.214981  0.389855  0.541666
4   0.578132  0.304780  0.789573  0.268851
5   0.094360  0.514878  0.419333  0.017010
6   0.279122  0.401132  0.722363  0.337094
7   0.444977  0.333254  0.643878  0.371528
8   0.724673  0.063281  0.345225  0.935403
9   0.905482  0.846500  0.585653  0.364495
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the column names on the underscore and convert to a tuple. Once you map each split column name to a tuple, pandas will convert the `Index` to a `MultiIndex` for you. From there we just need to call `swaplevel` to get the letter level to come first and reassign to the dataframe.

note: in my input dataframe I replaced the column name "amount_b" with "amount_B" because it lined up with your expected output so I assumed it was a typo

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("_", expand=True).swaplevel()

print(df)
          A                   B
      price    amount     price    amount
0  0.652826  0.941421  0.823048  0.728427
1  0.400078  0.600585  0.194912  0.269842
2  0.223524  0.146675  0.375459  0.177165
3  0.330626  0.214981  0.389855  0.541666
4  0.578132  0.304780  0.789573  0.268851
5  0.094360  0.514878  0.419333  0.017010
6  0.279122  0.401132  0.722363  0.337094
7  0.444977  0.333254  0.643878  0.371528
8  0.724673  0.063281  0.345225  0.935403
9  0.905482  0.846500  0.585653  0.364495
```

Comment: You could skip the `map(tuple)` part, with `expand=True`; it converts the columns into a MultiIndex: ``df.columns.str.split("_", expand=True).swaplevel()``

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I completely forgot about the `expand` argument, and I didn't know that would cast the `Index` to a `MultiIndex`. Great trick to know :)

Comment: Thank you! This solution is also working.